# Intuition concerning Schwartz kernels of Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider a (for example differential) operator $A$ acting on an appropriate function space over a smooth compact manifold without boundary.

Using the Schwartz kernel $K(x,y)dy$ of the operator, its action can be described as
$$
Af(x) = \int_M K(x,y)f(y)dy\,.
$$

Sometimes one may also have families of operators $A_t$ depending on a parameter which may for example describe time.

I was wondering whether there are "intuitive ideas" behind the kernel $K(x,y)$, for example
1) what does its value at the point $(x,y)$ tell us about the action of the operator? 
2)How can I translate something like a discontinuity into some insight regarding the behaviour of the abstract operator? (e.g. kernels of inverses to differential operators, which are pseudodifferential operators, are discontinuous at the diagonal)

Many thanks for your insight!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone will likely correct me, but I wouldn't expect too much. $\{K(x,y)\}_{(x,y)}$ is the continuous version of the matrix representation of the operator. And usually you don't get much information about an operator by looking at the entries of its matrix in some basis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have accepted it but was wondering, there are instances where the kernel is at least mentioned in the study of certain operators, for example I think for differential operators one always comments that their Schwartz kernels have singular support along the diagonal, and the heat kernel is also studied in order to understand the heat operator. Perhaps this is just talk as your answer would suggest -- would it better in your opinion to spend more time learning about more abstract operator theory instead? If so, what would be a good book to start?

Comment: (I have learned some basic theory for bounded operators, but this seems to be insufficient to understand the kind of operators I meet)

Answer (score 0):

A large part of modern harmonic analysis is about inferring properties of the operator $A$ like being bounded from $L^p$ to $L^q$, from properties of the kernel $K(x,y)$ and in particular its behavior near the diagonal. See, e.g., [the theory of Calderon-Zygmund operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_integral).